# An open set with end point real as a union of open sets with rational end point.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Suppose that we have the open interval of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ $(a,+\infty]$ and suppose that we want to write this as a union of open intervals of the same type but with rational endpoint.

**My attempt.** For the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, exists an decreasing sequence of rational $\{q_n\}$ such that $q_n\to a$, then $$(a,+\infty]=\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}(q_n,+\infty].$$

***Here's my test:***

if $x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} (q_n,+\infty]$, then $x\in (q_n,+\infty]$ for same $n\in\mathbb{N}$, since $q_n\ge a$ we have that $(q_n,+\infty]\subseteq (a,+\infty].$

**Edit for the vice versa**

Let $x\in (a,+\infty]$, since the sequence $\{q_n\}$ is decreasing exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a<q_n<x$ for all $n>n_0$, therefore $x\in (q_n,+\infty]$ for all $n>n_0$.

> **Question.** It's correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace "increasing" with "decreasing", and you will be correct. Since you're not sure of yourself, you should try proving it!

Comment: Thanks! I  corrected sure I'll try.

Comment: @TheoBenditHere's my test: if $x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} (q_i,+\infty]$, then $x\in (q_n,+\infty]$ for same $n\in\mathbb{N}$, since $q_n\le a$ we have that $(q_n,+\infty]\subseteq (a,+\infty].$ Vice versa, if $x\in (a,+\infty]$, from density of $\mathbb{Q}$ exists a $a<q<x$, then $x\in (q,+\infty].$ Right?

Comment: You still need to change “$q_n ≤ a$” into … and “$a < x < q$” into “$a < q_n < …$”?

Comment: Thanks! $q_n\ge a$

Comment: Since the sequence $\{q_n\}$ is decreasing, exists a $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $q_{n_0}\le x$, therefore $x\in (q_{n_0},+\infty].$ Right?

Comment: No need to bring $\frac1n$ into this. What is the inequality you need to show so that $x\in (q,\infty)$? But before that, where do you get $q$? The density of $\mathbb Q$ is useless to you since you did not take a union of $(q,\infty)$ over all rational $q$. You have to work with the sets that make up your union.

Comment: @DavidKSorry, but I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

(a,oo] = $\cup${ (r,oo] : a < r, r in Q }.

Comment: The OP asked whether his proof is correct.